# Working with audio in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

Am working on a speech recognition app on android, I would like to know how I can read the audio as stream of bytes and play it. Am currently using the below code to start and stop recording.

```
 void startRecording()
    {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.mp3";
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording()
    {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`AudioRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) for recording and [`AudioTrack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) for playback if you want raw bytes. `MediaRecord` will give an encoded audio format.

There are plenty of example online if you search for AudioRecord, so I won't go into the details, but it's not very complicated.